# Implementing page-flip-type animations in UIWebView on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, uiwebview

I'm using UIWebView on the iPhone to display EPUB content, but I'd like to simulate the page flipping 'experience' (display an animation of the page folding over) and then scrolling the content in my UIWebView down by the area of one screen -- effectively turning a page in reflowable non-paginated content. Should I stop dreaming, or would this be possible?

Comment: @ Hello matthewherren ,
I also want to read epub on iphone can you please tell me how do i read epub?

Comment: Hi Matthew, did you get somewhere with it?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780757/page-turn-animation-on-uiwebview-in-iphone

Answer (score 1):

What about making a copy of the `UIWebView`, scrolling it to the appropriate position, and then using the page flip transition to go from view to view, then deallocating the first `UIWebView`?