# page turn Animation on UIWebView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, uiwebview, epub

I am new to `iPad` developer,

I'm using UIWebView on the `iPhone` to display `EPUB` content, but I want to implement page turning animation similar to book.

I had seen many demos of page turn effects, but they all are related to view not `UIWebView`,
for eg: [see demo](https://nodeload.github.com/brow/leaves/zipball/master)
I want to implement this page turn effect. on `UIWebView`

would this be possible? or Should I stop dreaming.

**Thanks In Advance !**

Comment: Subview UIWebViews to UIPageViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this tutorial

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application

Comment: this tutorial is very nice, but it will work only for static pages, not for dynamic pages.

Comment: if you understand how static page works. I think there is no difficulty then to use it for dynamic

Comment: can you make it for me ? i will give you my +100 reputation

Answer (score 1):

I think You have better to use quatrzcore framework to load epub content.Then You can simply achieving this turn over animation by making each page an image.leaves in github is a great example for doing this

Comment: here i am rendering the epub in to the uiwebview in portrait mode its loaded the content but in landscape i need to display two page view could u have any idea